# Translating a data table without using VBA

Tags: excel

I have a data table with names in French. There are around 18 names (I haven't counted). Column A contains an identifier. Column B contains the data to translate. I would like to have a little translation table on the side that gives the equivalent between french and english. Example: "Ventes et soumissions" with "Sales and tendering" in the next cell. I would like to have a formula that I can drag down the whole list and have it look up the translation to write it in column C.

This could be done with multiple nested IFs and no translation table. The translations would be written directly in a massive formula. It could also be done easily with VBA but I would rather do it in excel directly because the tool would be maintained by people who do not know VBA. Does anyone know of a way more efficient than the multiple IFs?

Comment: `VLOOKUP` with all of the phrases translated already is the easy approach.  If your goal is to split the phrase and translate the pieces, then it depends heavily on how you're splitting, how many words are possible, and whether or not you can stand helper columns.  People have a hard enough time translating text with full featured applications. I suspect your constraints (Excel formulas only) will severely limit your options unless the possible phrases to translate are similarly limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your translation table should contain the French and English versions. Lets say it's in `Sheet2!A:B` where `A` is the French column and `B` is the English column.

If your data that you are translating is in `Sheet1!B1:B18` then in `Sheet1!C1` you can use a `VLOOKUP()` formula to grab the translation from your translation table:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1, Sheet2!A:B, 2, False)
```

This will look up `B1` into column `A` of `Sheet2` and return the corresponding value from Column `B` of `Sheet2`. You can copy this formula down to translate all of the rows in `Sheet1`